# NSRegularExpression:stringByReplacingMatchesInString Does not reconstruct string with multiple lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

Following section of code beautifully results: 
 `- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject { DLOG()`

```
- (void) putLogInFunctionCalls{

NSString *string = @"- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^-[^{]+\{" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ DLOG()", string]];

NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

}

But instead of putting just one line of input in the variable string if I try to read a code file say ViewController.m file that contains following code and put it in that variable: it does not work.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  ForCommonCoding
//
//  Created by A Programmer on 7/6/17.
//  Copyright ? 2017 A Programmer. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {
         [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];

     // Update the view, if already loaded.
}

- (void)sampleFunction {
    NSLog(@"This is sampleFunction");
}
@end
```

NSLog shows same as input. DLog() not appeneded Can anyone help solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you expects:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(-[^{]+\{)" options:NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"$1 DLOG()"];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

The are three problems with your code:

- NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines was missing but you're matching line start with `^`
- Matching group is missing in regex which allows you to use the matching result in replacement: `()`
- Replacement template string uses the whole `string` instead of the first match `$1`

Working Playground code:

```
let line = "- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {"
let file = "#import \"ViewController.h\"\n\n\n@implementation ViewController\n\n- (void)viewDidLoad {\n    [super viewDidLoad];\n\n    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.\n}\n- (void)setRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject {\n         [super setRepresentedObject:representedObject];\n\n     // Update the view, if already loaded.\n}\n\n- (void)sampleFunction {\n    NSLog(@\"This is sampleFunction\");\n}\n@end"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(-[^{]+\\{)", options: [.anchorsMatchLines])
regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: line, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, line.characters.count), withTemplate: "$1 DLOG()")
regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: file, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, file.characters.count), withTemplate: "$1 DLOG()")
```